# gtm.click not showing in summary window

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm making a trigger which fires on element click (Button) on my Add to cart button , When I click while on GTM Preview mode I cannot see the gtm.click in summary window , I also have clicked all the Click Variables inside Variables tab , what else can I do , or am I missing something?

I inspected the element of the button through firebug

Code:
`class="btn-add-to-cart">ADD TO CART`

The Trigger fires on

Some Clicks > Click Classes equals btn-add-to-cart

Tag Configuration

Track Type : Event

Label:{(Page URL)}

Advertising:

Enable Display Advertising Features Clicked

If that gtm.clicks tab shows I can inspect the Click Class variable for that and then it might work .

Currently it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **enable** the CLICKS from VARIABLE configuration ? Also make sure Tag is active

[image]